# Can't get A sum to join to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one contains a set of line items with amounts:

```
LEDGERTRANS:
Invoice ID  LineAmount
CM-00011054 -122.500000000000
CM-00011054 -246.000000000000
CM-00011054 -159.840000000000
CM-00011054 -39.3600000000000
```

And one with an item number i want, which happens to have a field, AMOUNTMST that is the sum of the above amounts

```
CUSTINVOICETRANS
INVOICE ID  AMOUNTMST
110100  -567.700000000000
400100   567.700000000000
```

I would like to take the sum of the CustInvoiceTrans lines, then grab the corresponding invoice id from the LedgerTrans Table.

This is for SQL Server 2008R2.

As I said, all I want is the InvoiceId. I think i'm making this too complicated. any help appreciated

Comment: Which dbms are you using? How does Ledgertable factor in? In your example query, you reference several fields that aren't represented in the example table structures above. It's very difficult to see exactly what you are trying to achieve, or what your question is. Do you mind rewriting a bit for clarity, adding the missing fields and table definitions, and making clear your question?

Comment: tried understanding your question - making it a bit generic will help. The question's wording is more complicated than the question :)

Comment: Please identify the tables by name - it helps us answer you better! There isn't an obvious way to map Invoice ID 110100 to the information in the other table, nor an obvious way to map Invoice ID 400100 to the other table.  Please show a soluble problem (or describe how it is known how to match the data). It is odd that the line item table doesn't have any other identifier than the combination of Invoice ID and LineAmount; so you can't have an order with two separate lines that cost the same amount.

Comment: The CUSTINVOICETRANS actually does have a Invoice id with the CM-* numbers on it. I am matching that to get the amounts from that table. but since there can be only one correct amount from the LEDGERTRANS table, i have to add up all of the order lines to match both the ID and the dollar amount. I am using the ABS function because it is the positive number i want.